# Google Cloud Engine - Issues When Mounting Storage Bucket To Use With WordPress

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I searched thoroughly and could not find any info on this issue.

Currently, I am building a Word Press site, hosted on Google Cloud's Compute Engine. The goal is to build an autoscaling WP site. I am currently attempting to build the instance template, which I can then use to deploy an instance group and subsequently setup the HTTP load balancer.

I am using a base Ubuntu 16.04 image, and from there I installed the rest of the LEMP stack.

I was successfully able to use the SQL proxy to connect to Cloud SQL so that all of the ephermal instances to be deployed will share the same database. To have the proxy initiated each time a new instance is spun up, I am using a startup script:

```
./cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql &
```

But here's my issue right now: the Word Press files. I can't figure out a way to have all of the instances use the same WP files. I already tried to use Google Cloud Storage FUSE, but when I mount the bucket at the root directory, it deletes all of the WordPress folders (wp-content, wp-admin, wp-includes).

It's as if the instance can't "see" the folders I have in the google cloud storage. Here was my work flow:

1. setup LEMP with WordPress--got the site working on the front end--all systems go
2. copied all of the files/folders in my root directory (/var/www/html/) to google cloud bucket

   gsutil -m cp -r /var/www/html/. gs://example-bucket/
3. Then I mounted the bucket at my directory

   gcsfuse --dir-mode "777" -o allow_other example-bucket /var/www/html/
4. But now, when I "ls" inside of the root directory from the Linux terminal, I DON'T see any of the WP folders (wp-includes, wp-admin, wp-content).

My end goal is to have a startup script that:

1. initiates the DB proxy so all WP instances can share the same DC
2. initiates the mounting of the google cloud bucket so all instances can share the same WP files

Obviously, that isn't working right now.

What is going wrong here? I am also open to other ideas for how to make the WP files "persistent" and "shared" across all of the ephemeral instances that the instance group spins up.

Answer (score 1):

Try:
sudo nano /etc/rc.local

In the file after:

---

#By default this script does nothing...

gcsfuse -dir-mode=777 -o allow_other [bucket-name] /var/www/html/[folder-name if apply]

exit 0

---

Will be work to mount in every scaled instance your bucket.

Hope this help for somebody i realized that you Q has more than 6 months.

:)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there should not be a problem with giving each instance its own WordPress files, unless those files will be modified by the instance.

Each instance can have its own copy of the Wordpress files and all instances can share a common Database. You can host the media files such as images, videos as well as Javascript and CSS files on a Content Delivery Network (CDN)

Comment: I'm not following your logic here--you may have missunderstood the question.

Comment: Each instance will of course need to access WP files; the issue revolves around making sure those EPHEMERAL instances have persistent and shared access to one main "storage area" so that changes can be made to that directory and flow down to whatever instances are running or any future instances.